# automata: using only Equivalence class to proove regularity

Tags: automata, equivalence, automaton

I have tried to go about this problem in several ways, and looked in several places with no answer. the question is as follow:

**[Question]**
Given two regular languages (may be referred to as finitely described languages ,idk) `L1` and `L2`, we define a new language as such:

```
L =  {w1w2| there are two words, x,y such that : xw1 is in L1, w2y is in L2}
```

I am supposed to use to show that `L is regular`, however I have the following restrictions:

- I must use Equivalence class, and no other way
- I cannot use `Rank(L)`, as in show a limit to the number of equivalence class, instead I must show them
- I may use the Closure properties that all regular languages hold

I am not expecting a full proof (though that would be appreciated) but an explanation to how to go about such a thing.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `L` is not regular for present statement, But I also feel you did some mistake in writing question.  may be `L = w1w2`.

Comment: yes I did mean w1w2. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

L =  {w1w2| there are two words, x,y such that : xw1 is in L1, w2y is in L2}  is regular if L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> are regular languages.

> L<sub>suff</sub>  = { w<sub>1</sub> | xw<sub>1</sub> ∈  L<sub>1</sub> }
>     L<sub>pref</sub>  = { w<sub>2</sub> | w<sub>2</sub>y ∈  L<sub>2</sub> }

**And,**

> L = L<sub>suff</sub>L<sub>pref</sub>

We can easily proof by construction Finite Automata for `L`.

Suppose Finite Automata(FA) for L<sub>1</sub> is  M<sub>1</sub> and FA for L<sub>2</sub> is M<sub>2</sub>.

**[SOLUTION]**
Non-Deterministic Finite Automata(NFA) for L can be drawn by introducing NULL-transition (^-edge) form every state in M<sub>1</sub> to every state in M<sub>2</sub>. then NFA can be converted into DFA.

e.g.
L<sub>1</sub> = {ab ,ac} and L<sub>2</sub> = {12, 13}

L = {ab, ac, 12, 13, a12, a2, ab12, ab2, a13, a3, ab13, ab3, ............}
**Note:** w<sub>1</sub> and w<sub>2</sub>  can be NULL

M<sub>1</sub> =is consist of  Q = {q<sub>0</sub>,q<sub>1</sub>,q<sub>f</sub>}  with edges:

> q<sub>0</sub> ---a----->q<sub>1</sub>,
>    q<sub>1</sub> ---b/c--->q<sub>f</sub>

Similarly :

M<sub>2</sub> =is consist of  Q = {p<sub>0</sub>,p<sub>1</sub>,p<sub>f</sub>}  with edges:

> p<sub>0</sub> ---1----->p<sub>1</sub>,
>        p<sub>1</sub> ---2/3--->p<sub>f</sub>

Now,  NFA for L called M will be consist of Q = {q<sub>0</sub>,q<sub>1</sub>,q<sub>f</sub>, p<sub>0</sub>,p<sub>1</sub>,p<sub>f</sub>} Where Final state of M is p<sub>f</sub> and edges are:

> q<sub>0</sub> ---a----->q<sub>1</sub>,
>    q<sub>1</sub> ---b/c--->q<sub>f</sub>,
>    p<sub>0</sub> ---1----->p<sub>1</sub>,
>    p<sub>1</sub> ---2/3--->p<sub>f</sub>,
>
> q<sub>0</sub> ----^----> p<sub>0</sub>,
>    q<sub>1</sub> ----^----> p<sub>0</sub>,
>    q<sub>f</sub> ----^----> p<sub>0</sub>,
>
> q<sub>0</sub> ----^----> p<sub>1</sub>,
>    q<sub>1</sub> ----^----> p<sub>1</sub>,
>    q<sub>f</sub> ----^----> p<sub>1</sub>,
>
> q<sub>0</sub> ----^----> p<sub>f</sub>,
>    q<sub>1</sub> ----^----> p<sub>f</sub>,
>    q<sub>f</sub> ----^----> p<sub>f</sub>

`^` means NULL-Transition.

Now, A NFA can easily convert into DFA.(I leave it for you)

**[ANSWER]**
DFA for L is possible hence L is Regular Language.

---

I will highly encourage you to draw DFA/NFA figures,  then concept will be clear.>

Comment: Let me know if you need more help on this.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

I am writing this answer, because I believe that the current available doesn't really satisfy the post requirements, i.e.

> I must use Equivalence class, and no other way

**Answer**

A more direct and simple approach is to **not** construct a DFA/NFA because of time reasons, but to just check if `#EquivalenceClasses < ∞` holds. Specifically, you would have the following ones here:

```
[w1] = {all w1 in L1}
[e]
[w1w2] = L
```

So `ind(R)`, the index of the equivalence relation, is `3`, therefore finite. Hence, `L` is regular. Q.E.D.

---

To make it more clear, just have a look at the definition of the equivalence relation for languager, i.e. `R_L`.

Moreover, regular languages are closed under concatenation. De facto you just need to concatenate the two DFA/NFA's into one.